# Least upper bound minus epsilon

Tags: real-analysis

**Problem:** Let $X$ be a set of real numbers with least upper bound $a$.  Prove that if $\epsilon>0$ there exists $x\in X$ such that $a-\epsilon < x \leq a$.

I see how the proof follows if $X$ has a greatest element (then choosing $x$ = greatest element of X would suffice.)  But what if $X$ doesn't have a greatest element?  How should I proceed?

Comment: If $a - \epsilon \ge x$  for all $x \in X$, then this would contradict with the "least" property of $a$...

Answer (score 2):

If there didn't exist such x, $a- \epsilon$ would be an upper bound, so..